# PyInstaller creating an empty Dist folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've gone through all the same questions asked before me and unfortunately they haven't fixed my issue. I have Python 3.7 installed as well as I thought perhaps 3.8 is not supported.

Here's the traceback it gives me in CMD

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\ctypes\_util.py", line 42, in check_null
    raise make_error(function, function_name)
OSError: [WinError 1920] The file cannot be accessed by the system.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\Desktop\KMQuiz\KM_vol2_ttkthemes.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 393, in assemble
    redirects=self.binding_redirects)[1:])
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 226, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 402, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 353, in getAssemblies
    res = GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 1005, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 168, in GetResources
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(filename, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system.')
```

Not sure whether the contents of the .spec file is necessary but i'll include it just in case as well

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['KM_vol2_ttkthemes.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Carl\\Desktop\\KMQuiz'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='KM_vol2_ttkthemes',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='KM_vol2_ttkthemes')
```

Comment: focus on this `LoadLibraryExW` , try to see why python is not able to load it in it's app